# Why packets sent through libpcap are filtered out for the local host?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, java

I have some simulator software running on linux (**linux_host)** in which is another linux (**linux_sim**) is running. The simulator uses libpcap to access the ethernet to provide network simulation on **linux_sim**. The network is brought up on **linux_host** and **linux_sim** OK. I can reach any host in LAN from **linux_sim** (it uses dhcp for example to setup IP).

The problem is that packets sent from **linux_sim** do not reach **linux_host**, however they travel in the opposite direction OK. The latter I can prove with wireshark running on **linux_host**: if I ping **linux_sim** on **linux_host** - I see ICMP requests and replies (from **linux_sim**) which do not reach **linux_host**, if I ping vice-versa - I see only ICMP requests (from **linux_sim**).

The following depicts roughly the architecture I have:

```
                   LAN
                    |
   linux_host-----[eth0]
                    |              
                  libpcap         
                    |
                 simulator
                    |
                linux_sim
```

PS

**linux_host** and **linux_sim** have different MAC addresses, IP's and from LAN look like independent linux hosts.

I tried on three different linux machines with the same result (with Debian,CentOS and Gentoo).

So, what can you recommend to check/tune/configure in this situation? As I suppose an unusual routing/filtering configuration is required for the **linux_host** in this case.

**UPDATE**

The broadcast traffic do reach from **linux_sim** to **linux_host** since I see that IP address is resolved with ARP (request broadcasts are replied) OK as the ping starts.

Comment: what simulator software are you using?  Is this a vm or something else?

Comment: This is our proprietary simulation sw, but I am sure this problem is not there since I see all correct packets in wireshark on linux host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a great test would be to put linux_host and linux_sim on different subnets.  Put a router (another linux box perhaps) on this VLAN and give it two sub-interfaces there with IPs in both subnets and have it be able to route between the boxes.  I think you are running into some sort of issue with reverse path detection.  Have you already turned that off?

http://www.wlug.org.nz/ReversePathFiltering

Comment: Good advice regarding RPF - I've checked - it's switched off already. Could it be due to method of how libpcap communicates with network interface? I mean the send procedure goes into so low that no routing/filtering/etc are not involved at all?

Comment: That would be my assumption too, but I think the only way to verify that would probably be some dtrace hooks which I am not very familiar with.  But the outcome would be interesting I think.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have much information about how your networking is configured.  If your simulator is accessing the outside world through a bridge interface, you have to consider what the NIC hardware (and it's driver) are doing.  For example, on most newer Intel NICs you have to disable GRO to get TCP working with bridged VMs.  There are also often problems with NIC hardware offload and IO-SRV.  Look through your drivers documentation for notes on bridging.